# Using <video> with <source>, where do you add the crossorigin attribute?

Tags: html, video

When using the `<video>` tag alone, one adds the crossorigin attribute like so:

```
<video src="blah" crossorigin="anonymous"></video>
```

However, I've had trouble finding out the correct placement of 'crossorigin' **when using multiple video sources**, for example:

```
<video>
<source src="/somesource.mp4">
<source src="/somesource.webm">
</video>
```

**Do you put the 'crossorigin' attribute on the `<video>` tag or the individual `<source>` tags?**

If the later, does this mean that each source can have individual crossorigin handling within the one video tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you put the 'crossorigin' attribute on the  tag or the individual  tags?

The W3C specs specify the crossorigin attribute on the video tag (or more precisely the HTMLMediaElement) but not on the src element (or again more precisely, the HTMLSourceElement).

So, assuming everyone follows the specs, which is always a rash assumption - see Margus's answer for exmple, you should put the cross origin attribute on the video tag rather than the individual source tags.

Comment: Thanks! For anyone else, the two relevant specs are here:

- [http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/media-elements.html](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/media-elements.html)
and here [http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-source-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-source-element)

Answer (score 0):

`crossOrigin` attribute not supported by Safari, alternative is to retrieve the image/video data base64 version with ajax and change url.

instead of writing :

```
<video controls crossorigin="anonymous" src="http://example.com/movie.mp4">
```

you would use

```
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'get',
                        url : videoUrlFromAnotherDomain,
                        crossDomain: 'true',
                        success: function(data) {
                            // get a base64 version of the video!
                            var base64 = window.btoa(data);
                            // get a new url!
                            var newURL = 'data:video/mp4' + ';base64,' + base64;
                            // set the src on the video source element to the new url
                            video.find("source").attr("src", newURL);
                        }
```